# How to link to a shared library with a relative path?

Tags: gcc, shared-library, ld

In the [man page for ld.so(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so), it says that

> When resolving library dependencies, the dynamic linker first inspects each dependency string to see if it contains a slash (this can occur if a library pathname containing slashes was specified at link time). If a slash is found, then the dependency string is interpreted as a (relative or absolute) pathname, and the library is loaded using that pathname.

How can `gcc` link against a library with a path with a slash? I have tried with `-l` but that seems to work only with a library name which it uses to search various paths, not with a path argument itself.

One follow-on question: when linking to a relative path in this way, what is the path relative to (e.g. the directory containing the binary or the working directory at runtime)?

All of the linking guides I find when searching discuss using `RPATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and `RUNPATH`. `RPATH` is deprecated and most discussions discourage using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. `RUNPATH` with a path starting with `$ORIGIN` allows for a link to a relative path, but it is a little fragile because it can be overridden by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I wanted to know if a relative path would be more robust (since I can't find anything discussing this I am guessing not, likely because the path is relative to the runtime directory).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If we (for the moment) ignore the `gcc` or linking portion of the question and instead modify a binary with [`patchelf`](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html) on a linux system

```
$ ldd hello
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd35584000)
        libhello.so.1 => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f02e4f6f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f02e533c000)
$ patchelf --remove-needed libhello.so.1 hello
$ patchelf --add-needed ./libhello.so.1 hello
$ ldd hello
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdb74fc000)
        ./libhello.so.1 => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2ad5c28000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2ad5ff5000)
```

We now have a binary with a relative path library, which if there exist suitable directories with `libhello.so.1` files present in them

```
$ cd english/
$ ../hello
hello, world
$ cd ../lojban/
$ ../hello
coi rodo
```

**we find that the path is relative to the working directory of the process**, which opens up all sorts of problems, especially [security](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254711/history-of-unix-not-including-current-directory-in-path) [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549671/doesnt-perl-include-current-directory-in-inc-by-default#46550384). There might be some productive use for this, testing different versions of a library, perhaps. It would likely be simpler to compile two different binaries, or `patchelf` in the necessary library without the complication of a relative working directory.

#### compile steps

`libhello` only has a `helloworld` call

```
$ cat libhello.c
#include <stdio.h>
void helloworld(void)
{
    printf("coi rodo\n");
}
```

and was compiled via

```
CFLAGS="-fPIC" make libhello.o
gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libhello.so.1 -o libhello.so.1.0.0 libhello.o -lc
ln -s libhello.so.1.0.0 libhello.so.1
ln -s libhello.so.1.0.0 libhello.so
```

and the `hello` that makes the `helloworld` call was compiled via

```
$ cat hello.c
int main(void)
{
    helloworld();
    return 0;
}
$ CFLAGS="-lhello -L`pwd`/english" make hello
```

#### without patchelf

In hindsight, modify the `gcc` command to use a relative directory path:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,./libhello.so.1 -o libhello.so.1.0.0 libhello.o -lc
$ cd ..
$ rm hello
$ CFLAGS="-lhello -L`pwd`/lojban" make hello
$ ldd hello | grep hello
        ./libhello.so.1 => not found
$ english
$ ../hello
hello, world
```

It's probably more sensible to compile the library in a normal fashion and then fiddle around with any binaries as necessary using `patchelf`.

Answer (score 6):

You would do this by passing options to the linker.  For instance, to run test-programs from ncurses' build-directory (which rely upon libraries not installed), I use an option like this (in the gcc command-line):

```
-Wl,-rpath,../lib
```

which embeds a relative pathname.  The same option can embed an absolute pathname:

```
-Wl,-rpath,../lib:/usr/local/ncurses6/lib
```

Doing that is useful for local testing, but not for installing on the system for a variety of reasons.  Debian has a policy against it, dating back to the 1990s, though coherent discussion is rare (see for example [RPATH issue](https://wiki.debian.org/RpathIssue) which collects some of the information).

Comment: FTR, unfortunately `-Wl,-rpath,../lib` can't seem to be used for overriding a path also specified directly as part of a shared lib filename, e.g. in a makefile, like `gcc test.c -Wl,-rpath,$(TESTDIR) $(LIBDIR)/testlib.so`), if my observation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you use gcc to compile simply, you just need to do like this:

```
gcc -o prog main.c ./liblib.so
```

After compile, the program has the same behavior as the thrig's answer.
I think this command should be only used in testing environment.